# How to create a shocker device safely, that would electrocute a user with a low charge

Tags: arduino, voltage, power, batteries, power-electronics

=====================================================

*As a disclaimer, I'm a novice when it comes to electrical engineering, I have a background in programming in comparison. I'm looking for assistance in guiding myself through the construction of said advice. I would be very grateful if any answering users allowed me to contact them via email or over the website for follow up questions to this initial post. I know what I want to build and would like to build it myself but I have very limited experience and equipment although I'm willing to purchase equipment on a as needed basis.*

=====================================================

Essentially I would like to build a device not too unlike a taser but an extremely weak variant as an example I imagine the device delivering a shock akin to an electric fence or a joke shocker pen. I want to be able to scale the charge up and down to a certain degree so I can establish the appropriate charge. Also I envision the device having multiple points of contact with a user therefore multiple shockers but I would prefer to have it work from the same battery or batteries.

Any assistance or advice on how I should go about this would be appreciated. I'm not really sure where to start and would like to avoid wasting as much time as possible.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how the site works. Then edit your post to ask a specific design question that can be answered on the site.

Comment: don't even think about it.

Comment: A cat and an amber rod work well, if you can find a cooperative cat.

Answer (score 6):

Anyone that has to ask here **should absolutely not be doing this**.

There are too many issues with safety that trying to explain them all here would be unreasonable.  This is something you simply shouldn't do.

Fahgeddaboudit.

Answer (score 2):

I agree 100% with Olin. Even if someone one this site gave you good information as to how to achieve your goal, we cannot take responsibility if you don't follow that advice and wind up building a device that would indeed, to quote from your title. "electrocute a user".

Answer (score 0):

Buzzers are simple to make with SPDT NC contacts in series with 3V Li battery and lowest current 5V coil and hand momentary switch.

Comment: I think what Tony means is that you use a relay powered through the NC contacts which switches itself off and on (buzzes). There is a high voltage across the coil. It was popular for just this purpose when I was a nipper.

Comment: Yes you can also use magnetic buzzers with the internal contacts exposed or a relay. Same concept